# Transfer statistics per process or destination, not interface

Tags: network, command-line, unix

I would like to log upload statistics for an application I run on my Mac.

Now, I know that with `netstat -ib` I can access statistics per network interface.
I also know that with `lsof -i` I can get a list of which connections each of the processes is maintaining. And finally I know that with `iftop` I can monitor in real time how much is flowing between my machine and a remote address. But none of this achieves what I am looking for.

I am looking to get columns similar to the `Ibytes` and `Obytes` columns I get from `netstat -ib`, but get those for a specific remote network address OR for a specific local process ID.

Answer (score 1):

Best I've been able to come up with myself is to write a script that runs `iftop -f "dst net REMOTE_IP" -t` in the background, redirecting the output, and after a certain timeout kills the process, and then grep/awk my way through the redirected output. Hardly elegant.